# Looking for Reasons NOT to put SharePoint 2010 in Cloud

Tags: sharepoint-2010, cloud

I am looking for a laundry list of reasons why a large company with 24000 employees would NOT want to put their Primary SharePoint system for their internet into the cloud?
What are the limitations and challenges compared to operating your own farm servers.

Thank you for your thoughts.

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: Not really just a general discussion I am sure many companies are facing.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the provider, they might limit your choice of webparts, addons, solutions, etc.

Check for:

1. Addons that contain unmanaged code (BPOS does not allow this, for example)
2. Addons that need to elevate privileges
3. Anything that needs to run in a full-trust environment

Ask about any other possible limitation.  At 24k users, you probably are only looking at high-end providers, but ask, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

You mean apart from the fact that hosting your entire sensitive company data, trade secrets, potential HR data at a third party that may or may not do a good job securing it from other customers on the same cloud may be just a tiny little risk?

Or that if the provider has an outage (like the Amazon S3 blackout yesterday) leaves you somewhat powerless and at the mercy of the provider?